# SourceGenerator: Attribute NamedArguements is empty

Tags: c#, roslyn, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I'm trying to build my first source generator, the source generator is designed to register hangfire recurring jobs and a basic version is working similar to the. You can see this on the [master branch in this project](https://github.com/IeuanWalker/Hangfire.RecurringJob.Generator/blob/master/Scr/Attributes/RecurringJobAttribute.cs)

Idea is, you'll be able to add an attribute too the recurring job class -

```cs
[RecurringJob("DeleteOldReportsAtMidnight", "* *678 * *")]
public class DeleteOldReports
{
    public void Execute()
    {
    }
}
```

The source generator automatically generates -

```cs
namespace TestSolution;

// <auto-generated/>

using Hangfire;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

public static class ServiceRegistrationExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection RegisterServicesFromTestSolution(this IServiceCollection sc)
    {
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<TestSolution.DeleteOldReports>("DeleteOldReportsAtMidnight", x => x.Execute(), "* *678 * *");
        return sc;
    }
}
```

And all the user has too do is call the registration method at start up

```cs
ServiceRegistrationExtensions.RegisterServicesFromTestSolution(services)
```

---

The bit im struggling with now is using more advanced attribute with optional parameters. You can see my [desired attribute here on a different branch](https://github.com/IeuanWalker/Hangfire.RecurringJob.Generator/blob/MoreAdvancedAttribute/Scr/Attributes/RecurringJobAttribute.cs)

Im able to get the attributes on the class but the `NamedArguments` is always empty

[image: Debug screenshot showing now named arguments]

Comment: Your "different branch" is 404. Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Sorry, I ended up just doing it based on the order of the constructor argument, but if you know of a solution that allows me to use the name arguments, I'm all ears (or will accept a PR for it)

https://github.com/IeuanWalker/Hangfire.RecurringJob/blob/1cac83faca719bc939dc58949a2fc6672f817321/Scr/IeuanWalker.Hangfire.RecurringJob.Generator/RecuringJobGenerator.cs#L54C1-L80C4

Answer (score 0):

It's been some time since i did SG's, but i think the problem is, that you're not actually using named arguments, wich should look like this:
`[RecurringJob(action: "DeleteOldReportsAtMidnight", pattern: "* *678 * *")]`
The names of the parameters of the constructer are irrelevant here, if i remember correctly.
You can even use the semantic and or syntax model there, to generate the matching constructor for given parameters and feed dynamic information into your SG.